# Singleton class with Java enum for holding global states in a Multi-threaded application

Tags: java, multithreading, enums, singleton

I need to share some global states (button status) between EDT and a bunch of worker threads. When the EDT changes the value, it needs to appear immediately in all other worker threads. I have designed a singleton class with Java enum as follows:

```
public enum ButtonState {
     INSTANCE;

     private volatile boolean showPhase = false;

     public boolean showPhase() {
          return showPhase;
     }

     public void setShowPhase(boolean showPhase) {
          this.showPhase = showPhase;
     }
}

//Client Code:
if (ButtonState.INSTANCE.showPhase()) {
      // show phase
      // do stuff
      ButtonState.INSTANCE.setShowPhase(false);
}
```

1. Is this the correct way for achieving my goal or is there any other better approach?
2. Do I really need to make the `showPhase` **volatile**?

Comment: check out Observer Design Pattern http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java

Comment: More about thread safe observer design pattern, https://www.techyourchance.com/thread-safe-observer-design-pattern-in-java/

Comment: You might also want to check out options in implementing singleton,
http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples

Comment: I also have a double-checking thread-safe singleton implementation. But many people suggest that `enum` is the best way to achieve it (If we do not need lazy loading). However, Observer design pattern might be a good option. I will look on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your use case if only requirement is to shared flag among the multiple thread your approach looks correct and thread safe as you are using volatile.So the change value will be visible to all thread.This is a pull model all worker thread needs to be access the flag by there own.

Or you can use push based model as suggested above to use Observer patter to push to all worker thread any changes in the flag.I think 2nd approach is good as it will notify the worker immediately and all thread will get the notification same time.In your approach may be there will be a delay .